# Check if row value is within a range and assign the range group to a new column

Tags: r

I have a column of ages that range from 18 to 80. How do I add a new column that will assign an "age group" to each row? For example, if a row has age 24, I would like to assign "18-29" for the "age group" column. Similar, if a row has age 45, I would like to assign "39-50". The age groups are: 18-29, 30-39, 40-49, 50-59, 60-69, 70-80

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
grps = c("18-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59", "60-69", "70-80")
grps[findInterval(age, c(18, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80), TRUE)]
```